# Android Studio 1.0 RC aapt permission denied error

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and have installed the latest Android studio stable version. After completing initial installation, I get this error.

```
Error : Cannot run program "/path/android-sdk-Linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=13 , Permission denied
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResourses'
```

This is my first try with Android app development so please give me detailed instructions on how to handle this error.

Comment: From where did you install Android Studio? If its an archive setup file, have you tried extracting it to your home folder and running it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928164/android-studio-cannot-find-aapt), it's a link to an answered question in stackoverflow.
try these:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```